# Facebook's "fb_sig" and "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas"

Tags: php, facebook, oauth-2.0

I'm trying to get the "fb_sig" parameters that facebook is supposed to provide by using this code:

```
$parms='';
foreach ($_REQUEST as $name=>$val)
{
  if (substr($name,0,6)!='fb_sig') continue;
  if ($parms!='') $parms.='&';
  $parms.=$name.'='.$val;
}
```

I need that in order to send those parameters to the php code that needs to use facebook api (ie. to get a friends list) , and so far it used to work ok. I got the code from here:
http://www.foobots.net/breakouts.html

But when I activate the "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" to be able to use the facebook credits api, then "Parms" ends up being an empty string. No "fb_sig" parameters at all. And when I parse the signed_request, they're not there either.

Is it possible to use "OAuth 2.0 for Canvas" and still have access to "fb_sig" parameters?

Answer (score 1):

Your app will be set to receive either "fb_sig" parameters OR the "signed_request" parameter. The fb_sig parameters are the old way Facebook used to do it. signed_request is the new way.  By decoding the signed_request parameter, I believe you can access the same information as contained in the individual fb_sig_* parameters.

For older apps, you can swap between fb_sig_* and signed_request by changing the advanced option "signed_request for Canvas" in your advanced app settings.

New apps ONLY have the option of signed_request, no option to change it in the App settings.

Note, this is as of September 2011, by next year all this may have changed.. again.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at

[Facebook Canvas Auth](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/guides/canvas/#auth)

[Facebook Signed Request](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/signed_request/)

I dont think both methods at the same time will be working! Hope that helps

Comment: Thanks! I'll keep looking. My app is done in flash, and it calls a php file to retrieve the user's friends. Since that php does a require_login() then it requires the auth data too (cookies are unreliable). I used to solve that by sending the "fb_sig" parameters in the url, but now that I dont have them anymore I'm not sure what to send, other than sending the signed request (or the data that it contains)